# SAS-SQL - put result in 1 cell, not in many

Tags: sql, sas

I am using a basic select statement to pull some accounts. 
I need to output those accounts in a single cell, and not rows of accounts.

Comment: How do you want it? Comma separated?

Comment: comma is fine, yes

Comment: Are you using sql-server?

Comment: no. sql via SAS

Comment: SELECT STUFF(
                 (SELECT ',' + CONVERT(varchar,accounts) FROM #YourTable FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, ''
               ) as output

Comment: check if it works.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/how-to-concatenate-text-from-multiple-rows-into-a-single-text-string-in-sql-serv

Comment: doesn't work; getting an error. I must stress that I am using SQL syntax via SAS, while connecting to database in TERADATA.

Comment: Update the question to show your basic select statement and any error messages that are appearing in the SAS log.  Are you using the DMS (desktop SAS), Enterprise Guide or SAS Studio client ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
PROC SQL;
   CREATE TABLE WORK.WANT AS 
   SELECT /* Concatenated */
                     (cats(t1.COLUMN_1, ', ', t1.COLUMN_2)) AS ConcatenatedColumns
      FROM WORK.HAVE t1;
QUIT;
```

I guess you need to have concatenated results from some table?

cats() function can be used to concat values of different columns, with removed  leading and trailing blanks.

Comment: please note output columns will be in a string format